# Chrome Android hiding keyboard when switching between inputs

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

**Chrome on Android**

I am having trouble switching between two inputs. The HTML is simply

```
<input type="text"/> 
<input type="text"/>
```

When I type text into the first input and then click on the second input the on screen keyboard goes away. This makes me have to click on the second input again in order to show the keyboard. It is really annoying.

I have tried giving them a `tabindex` but that didn't help. I also tried putting them into a `form` and that didn't help.

Here is a fiddle showing the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/k9bnd2gy/4/show/

Comment: I tried this fiddle in my moto e 2nd gen (lollipop) and works fine. It would be easier to identify the issue if you provide more information.

Comment: @muhammedbasil I was able to reproduce it on three different phones including my Nexus 5. The trick is that you have to put text into the first input before clicking on the second input in order to show the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using `setSelectionRange` when the `focus` event is fired.

This works because it forces the cursor into the `input`.

```
$('input').on('focus',function(event){
    this.setSelectionRange(0, 0);  
});
```